# Error with NSNumberFormatter currencySymbol

Tags: ios, currency, nsnumberformatter

I have a problem getting the currencySymbol of my NSNumberFormatter.
I use a NSNumberFormatter with a currency code "EUR".
When I format prices, the symbol is correct, I get the € symbol.
However, when I want to get just the currencySymbol with the method [formatter currencySymbol], the symbol $ is returned.
If I manually set the currencySymbol (with "A" for instance) everything will work fine and the method [formatter currencySymbol] will return the "A" symbol.


Here is my code

```
// Create formatter
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencyCode:@"EUR"];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

// Log the currency symbol
NSLog(@"[formatter currencyCode] : %@", [formatter currencyCode]);
NSLog(@"[formatter currencySymbol] : %@", [formatter currencySymbol]);
NSLog(@"[formatter currencySymbol] : %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);
[formatter setCurrencySymbol:@"A"];
NSLog(@"[formatter currencySymbol] : %@", [formatter currencySymbol]);
NSLog(@"[formatter currencySymbol] : %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);
```

Here are the console results :

```
2012-01-17 12:29:11.108[4545:207] [formatter currencySymbol] : $
2012-01-17 12:29:11.109[4545:207] [formatter currencySymbol] : €0.00
2012-01-17 12:29:11.110[4545:207] [formatter currencySymbol] : A
2012-01-17 12:29:11.111[4545:207] [formatter currencySymbol] : A0.00
```

I cannot force the currencySymbol since it can change.
Is there a way to get the right currencySymbol corresponding to a given currencyCode ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're missing the first NSLog from the console results.

Comment: Same issue here! `currencySymbol` just isn't returning what it's supposed to - as far as we can tell from the docs what it thinks it's supposed to do.........

Comment: Downvote because did not bother to check answers and mark one as right.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in NSNumberFormatter, have filed a radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4968182565568512

Answer (score 2):

To get the **currency symbol** you can use `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` with `NSLocale`:

```
   NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
   NSString* cs = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol
                                 value:currencyCode];
```

To get the localized name ('*US Dollar*', '*Japanese Yen*', ..) you can use `NSLocaleCurrencyCode`:

```
   NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
   NSString* cc = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode
                              value:currencyCode];
```

where `currencyCode` is the currency code (JPY, USD, EUR, ..) you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that `[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];` overwrites some of the configuration you did prior to it. You may want to try movig that line to the top (just after the alloc/init line).

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the $ instead of the €

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it. It gives me "USD".

Comment: I wonder if there's a relationship between `internationalCurrencySymbol` and `currencySymbol`. The Apple doc leaves a lot to the imagination. I wonder if you can finally get € in `currencySymbol` after you do `[formatter setInternationalCurrencySymbol:@"EUR"];`?

Comment: No. The currencySymbol is still $.

Comment: `internationalCurrencySymbol` gives you the ISO symbol for the selected locale like EUR, `currencySymbol` gives you the actual symbol like €

Answer (score 0):

Try this  formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";
Provide the desired Currency Code here it will return proper symbol

Answer (score -1):

i have used the following code/methods to get the currency from a float value

```
 +(NSString *) formatCurrencyTypeFloat: (float )val {

 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"us_ES"];
    or
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];;
    [formatter setLocale:locale]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:val]]);
    return [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:val]];

}



+(NSString *) formateCurrencyTypeFloat:(float)val withSign:(NSString *)currencySign{
    NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
    NSNumber          * n;

    fmt = [[ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ]autorelease];
    n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: val];

    [ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
    [ fmt setCurrencySymbol: currencySign ]; //==> currencySign can be = @"$";
    [ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];


    return [ fmt stringFromNumber:n];
}

+(NSString *) formateCurrencyTypeFloat:(float)val withCode:(NSString *)currencyCode{
        NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
        NSNumber          * n;

        fmt = [[ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ]autorelease];
        n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: val];

        [ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
        [fmt setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];//====>@"USD";
        [ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];


        return [ fmt stringFromNumber:n];
    }
```

Comment: ..and that relates to the question how?